# Spring Session 1.0.0.M1 cookie domain attribute

Tags: spring, spring-security, session-cookies, spring-session

I have integrated Spring Session with Redis into my SpringBoot app. It seems that all works well except the cookie domain attribute. I just found how to set the cookie session domain attribute for in tomcat i.e. method "setSessionCookieDomain", but that does not work. for example.
I had configured domain attribute in the context of the tomcat for example the domain attribute of the cookie.

```
@Bean 
    public TomcatContextCustomizer tomcatContextCustomizer() {
        System.out.println("TOMCATCONTEXTCUSTOMIZER INITILIZED");
        return new TomcatContextCustomizer() {

            @Override
            public void customize(Context context) {
                context.addServletContainerInitializer(new WsSci(), null);
                context.setUseHttpOnly(true);
                context.setPath("/");
                context.setSessionCookiePath("/");
                context.setSessionCookieDomain(".127.0.0.5");
//              context.setSessionCookieDomain(".localhost");
//              context.setSessionCookieDomain(".test.blabla.com");

            }           

        };
    }
```

When i open the https trace in wireshark and click follow ssl  stream,  here is what i get. All other attributes are listed except the domain. So my question is how do I set the domain attribute correctly in Spring Session 1.0.0.M1, Does spring session somehow override the tomcat context?

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.5:8888
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Lang: keep-alive

: keep-alive

: keep-alive

: keep-alive

: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'
X-WebKit-CSP: default-src 'self'
X-Application-Context: application:Production
Set-Cookie: SESSION=5d0a738f-f011-4e43-a1ee-d691b8eba94c; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Conten10:01:27 GMT

10:01:27 GMT

10:01:27 GMT

10:01:27 GMT

10:01:27 GMT

<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. Spring Session should allow configuring the domain via the SessionCookieConfig but doesn't. I have created [gh-87](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/87) to address this.

Comment: Rob, glad that the question got answered.